# There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element

Tags: jaxb, spring-ws, xjc

I am using spring ws to implement my web service.
I am getting the following error in web service
"There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element test"
test is having a @XmlElementRef.

While creating the jaxb context I have used ContextPath set to the package name.

I have done the following things:

1. Used xjc parse to convert from WSDL to pojos.
2. I had multiple WSDL's so the ObjectFactory was getting overwritten. So I just renamed the objectfactory prefix with WSDL. A.wsdl will have AObjectFactory etc. So I dont have any ObjectFactory class.

I think when looking for @XmlElementDecl it looks for "ObjectFactory" class and then it cant find it, bcoz if I rename my AObjectFactory to ObjectFactory this works.

My question is:

1. Can @XmlElementRef not refer to renamed object factory created by me?
2. Can @XmlElementRef be avoided somehow?
3. Can we have multiple ObjectFactories?
4. Also how does @XmlElementRef and @XmlElementDecl works if we do not create ObjectFactories at all.

Any help will be great.

Answer (score 0):

> While creating the jaxb context I have used ContextPath set to the
>   package name.

When you create a `JAXBContext` by context path, the JAXB implementation is going to look for a class called `ObjectFactory` that is annotated with `@XmlRegistry`.

> I had multiple WSDL's so the ObjectFactory was getting overwritten.

Generally there should be one `ObjectFactory` per namespace/package.  If the `ObjectFactory` was getting overwriiten perhaps you were trying to force everything to the same package name.

> So I just renamed the objectfactory prefix with WSDL. A.wsdl will have
>   AObjectFactory etc. So I dont have any ObjectFactory class.

When the class annotated with `@XmlRegistry` is called something other than `ObjectFactory` you need to either:

1. Include a text file called `jaxb.index` in the same package as your domain model that contains the short name of all your classes in that package annotated with `@XmlRegistry`.
2. Bootstrap the `JAXBContext` of the generated classes annotated with `@XmlRegistry`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For #1 - I have included all the @XmlRegistry files in jaxb.index. For #2 - I am using spring so have used <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="Marshaller" ContextPath="path of the package"> Am I missing something?

Comment: @user1630693 - What does your `jaxb.index` look like?  Also what happens when you try creating the `JAXBContext` outside of Spring?